# Writing HTML / PHP Code inside an input/Textarea

Tags: php, html

I have found out that if a user writes in an input php/HTML code the code will excecute in my admin panel. Can this damage my system ? And if yes how can I disable it?

I will appreciate any answers!

Comment: This wont happen automatically. You will have to have coded something to make it happen!!

Comment: I think you mention a kind of SQL injection, but you have give more detailed information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove HTML and PHP tags with

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

result:

```
Test paragraph. Other text
<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
```

source: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to ***always filter data that comes from outside the application.*** So I mean every input that is given to the application. Particular attention must be given by the programmer to **the way in which to execute the queries to the database**. Since database queries can also be made using parameters that come from the user or more generally from outside the application.

1. **Remove all HTML tags from the input** before they are used to run queries or saved to the DATABASE.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
strip_tags ( string $string , array|string|null $allowed_tags = null )
```

2. **Pay particular attention to the formatting of queries** and input parameters before running database queries to avoid **SQLinjection**

an interesting article about it : https://www.ptsecurity.com/ww-en/analytics/knowledge-base/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-attacks/

**Cyber ​​Security is a very broad topic** and I don't think it can be expressed here in just one answer.

Dealing with this topic requires more and more IT requirements such as, for example, **knowing Programming**

**This answer is intended to be a starting point to deepen the subject**

Comment: i have researched too a little bit now. What do you think about htmlspecialchars($text) ?

Comment: htmlspecialchars($text)  becomes useful if you want visualize html or script code in your site  like Stack Overflow for example. This function do not remove html tags but replace it with special chars . So the Browser interprets this chars  and can show you the code  whitout  execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely it effect the project, not only html and PHP also SQL queries and JavaScript code also.

For prevention you have to validate the input using JavaScript or jQuery.